# use a javascript array to fill up a drop down select box

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a text file which I am reading and storing the data in a javascript array, it's a list of cuisines. I want to use the array to fill up a drop down select box. I know how to hard code in the values for the drop down box (using  correct me if i'm wrong) but I want to be able to use the array to fill it up instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];            
</script>

<select id="CusineList"></select>
```

I have hard coded an array for simplicity, the "CuisineList" is my drop down box

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601028/how-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-element-in-javascript

Comment: If you are reading this text file on the server, you probably want to generate the array using PHP or whatever server language you're using.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to iterate through your array. For each string, create a new `option` element, assign the string as its `innerHTML` and `value`, and then append it to the `select` element.

```
var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];     
var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
for(var i = 0; i < cuisines.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = cuisines[i];
    opt.value = cuisines[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/kGgkE/)

**UPDATE: Using `createDocumentFragment` and `forEach`**

If you have a very large list of elements that you want to append to a document, it can be non-performant to append each new element individually. The `DocumentFragment` acts as a light weight document object that can be used to collect elements. Once all your elements are ready, you can execute a single `appendChild` operation so that the DOM only updates once, instead of `n` times.

```
var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];     

var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

cuisines.forEach(function(cuisine, index) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = cuisine;
    opt.value = cuisine;
    fragment.appendChild(opt);
});

sel.appendChild(fragment);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/1qja2vg2/)

Comment: It is written as "CusineList" in original question

Comment: is there a way to stop the select element showing up empty for a split second before the options are added?

Comment: Could not manage to make work none of the 2 solutions (no matter the browser) .appendChild(opt) generates an error !

Answer (score 4):

This is a part from a REST-Service I´ve written recently.

```
var select = $("#productSelect")
for (var prop in data) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = data[prop].ProduktName
    option.value = data[prop].ProduktName;
    select.append(option)
}
```

The reason why im posting this is because appendChild() wasn´t working in my case so I decided to put up another possibility that works aswell.

Comment: How i can add option like "Choice" as first option?

Comment: this is also assuming that jQuery is being used, for javascript use `document.getElementById("productSelect")`