# Create an HTML Dropdown From a Javascript Array Without Duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu

Using a [previously answered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255219/use-a-javascript-array-to-fill-up-a-drop-down-select-box) as a reference, I created a function that populates a dropdown list in my HTML doc from an existing javascript array.

Here's the HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose action</legend>
        <p>Choose your action and click next</p><br />
            <select id="trigger"></select>
</fieldset>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
var guns =
    [
        ["Smith and Wesson 500", "Revolver", "Full Frame", 50, "sada"], //model, type, frame, cal, trigger
        ["Glock 19", "Semi", "Compact", 9, "striker"],
        ["Smith and Wesson M and P Shield 9", "Semi", "Compact", 9, "striker"],
        ["Ruger Alaskan", "Revolver", "Full Frame", 44, "dao"],
        ["Ruger SR9", "Semi", "Compact", 9, "striker"],
        ["Desert Eagle", "Semi", "Full Frame", 50, "sada"],
        ["Smith and Wesson M and P Shield 40", "Semi", "Compact", 40, "striker"]
    ]   

var triggerDropdown = function(){
    var sel = document.getElementById('trigger');
    for (var i = 0; i < guns.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = guns[i][4];
        opt.value = guns[i][4];
        sel.appendChild(opt);
        }
    };
```

**My challenge:**

Populate `trigger` *without duplicates*.  Also, the solution must not require me to permanently change `guns` (I found a few other helpful SO posts, but most of them involve first removing duplicates from the array...in this case, I don't have the option).

Thank you!

Comment: You say you can't change `guns`, but you can change a copy of it: `var gunsCopy = guns.slice(0)` (just don't modify any of the inner arrays, or you'll be changing `guns` too). Remove the duplicates from the copy, and use that to populate the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building the list, keep track locally of the keys you've already used:

```
var triggerDropdown = function(){

    var already = {};
    var sel = document.getElementById('trigger');
    for (var i = 0; i < guns.length; i++) 
    {
      var val = guns[i][4];

      if (! already[val]) 
      {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = val;
        opt.value = val;
        sel.appendChild(opt);

        already[val] = true;
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked very well.  I was going down this path while trying to figure it out, but kept falling all over myself.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Paul!

Comment: @PaulRoub, Probably the best way, however you should have a look at JavaScript best practices http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/.

Comment: @plalx Bookmarked--can't wait to read, and find out all the crap I've been doing wrong :).  For real, thank you for the reference!

Comment: There's Javascript best practices, and then there's "close enough to the original code to make the differences clear", which seemed more helpful in this case.

Comment: @PaulRoub, It doesn't hurt to learn more than a single thing ;) But yeah, it is probably easier to understand without too many changes.

Comment: And to be clear - the Opera article is well worth reading, and on a good day I follow much of it in my own code.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate array with just the triggers:

```
var triggers = function(guns) {
  var unique = {};

  return guns.reduce(function(current, item) {
    if (!(item[4] in unique)) {
      current.push(item[4]);
      unique[item[4]] = 1;
    }
    return current;
  }, []);
}(guns);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/eliyam/2/)

Then iterate over `triggers` as per normal.

See also: [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Short but quite inefficient, it's a lot better to use a lookup object and loop once.

Comment: @plalx Agreed and updated; looping over the `guns` array and immediately populating would be even better, but that answer has been given already :)

Comment: Way better now! The advantage of this one would be if the array has to be reused ;) However, I think it's a better practice to wrap a self-executing function in `()`.