# How to pass java array values to the html Drop Down Menu

Tags: spring-mvc

I followed lot of tutorials for find this. I had many answer with jsp. But i need do this with html

```
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model){

int values[]={33,34,35,36};
return "index";

}
```

I need to pass this array values to the html drop down menu in the my index.html file. Please help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Java script will  help you out here. You  Can give AJAX call from  Javascript or jQuery to  get the response from  server.

This link will help  you to  put data in select box from javascript 
[use a javascript array to fill up a drop down select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255219/use-a-javascript-array-to-fill-up-a-drop-down-select-box)

Read Something about AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/