# Populate array elements in dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add array elements to dropdownlist using javascript and refered the following links but it did not work:

- [JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array)
- [use a javascript array to fill up a drop down select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255219/use-a-javascript-array-to-fill-up-a-drop-down-select-box)

**Code :**

```
var itemArray=new Array();
var ddlItems=document.getElementById("ddlitemslist").value;
itemArray=["a","b","c"];

for(var i=0;i<itemArray.length;i++)
{
    var opt = itemArray[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");

    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;

    ddlItems.option.value=el; /*throws error that 'option' is not part of function*/
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you assign an array to variable, you don't have to init it with `new Array()`, because you will just overwrite it.

By using `new Array()` you have created a new, empty array. 
Then you have basically overwrited it with a different array - `itemArray = ["a","b","c"]`

If you want to push the dynamically created options to the `ddlItems` element, use `appendChild`.

**Note**: In your particular case, if you want to catch the this `select` from the DOM, use just `document.getElementById()` without `.value`, because we are going to reference to its other attributes, not `value` itself.

```js
var ddlItems = document.getElementById("ddlitemslist"),
    itemArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
      var opt = itemArray[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      ddlItems.appendChild(el);
    }
```

```html
<select id='ddlitemslist'></select>
```

Comment: The main problem doesn't come from the array initialisation... it's just an extra line that doesn't break the code buts better to remove it.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Isn't it clearly visible in the code snippet? Anyways - I've noted it (:

Answer (score 0):

> throws error that 'option' is not part of function

The error you get explain it self, you're trying to call `.option.value` on `ddlitemslist` value and not on the object.

You should not return the `value` in the initialisation of `ddlItems` variable but the object instead, like :

```
var ddlItems=document.getElementById("ddlitemslist").value;
```

Should be :

```
var ddlItems=document.getElementById("ddlitemslist");
```

**NOTE :** No need for `var itemArray=new Array();`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var itemArray=new Array(); //You could remove this line
var ddlItems = document.getElementById("ddlitemslist"),
itemArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
  var opt = itemArray[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");

  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;

  ddlItems.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id='ddlitemslist'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select `select` element and then while iterating over array create `option` elements as children of `select` element.

You need to replace

```
var ddlItems=document.getElementById("ddlitemslist").value;
```

with

```
var ddlItems=document.getElementById("ddlitemslist");
```