# Populate HTML <select> with Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, leaflet

I'm attempting to populate a HTML selection box from a JavaScript array, however when I run my page my console is outputting the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at hello.html:113
```

However, because it is created by JavaScript `innerHTML` I cannot select it. Is there another way of selecting this?

```
var police_api_dates = ["&date=2017-03",];
var info = L.control();
info.onAdd = function (mymap) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

info.update = function (properties) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<select id="parent"></select><h4>Highlighted Postcode</h4>' +  (properties ?
        '<b> Postcode: ' + properties.Name
        : 'Hover over a state');
};
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
for ( var pos = 0; pos < police_api_dates.length; pos++)
{
    //create an <option> to add the <select>
    var child = document.createElement("option");

    //assign values to the <option>
    child.textContent = police_api_dates[pos]
    child.value = pos;

    //attach the mew <option> to the <selection>
    parent.appendChild(child);
}


info.addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: `var parent = document.getElementById("parent");` is only evaluated **once** when JS executes this line. Later, in `info.update()`, you replace this element with a new element (even though that has the same id, it's a different element).

Comment: Would it be possible to suggest a fix, as you have pointed out I can still not see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Just delete the line `var parent = document.getElementById("parent");` and you're good to go. This restores the default browser behaviour of making id'd elements accessible by their id without having to declare a variable and using document.getElementById.

Comment: I have deleted var parent = document.getElementById("parent"); and parent.appendChild(child);

Comment: However my problem is now that the selection box appears empty instead of displaying what is in the array

Comment: `parent.appendChild(child);` must not be deleted.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: parent.appendChild is not a function"

Comment: You need to make sure that at the moment in time when `parent.appendChild(child);` is executed that the DOM has an element with `id=parent`.

Comment: this._div.innerHTML = '<select id="parent"></select> is this not created on this line though?

Comment: That is inside a function, and only executed when the function is called.

Comment: This code has many issues. Arguments are passed and not used, `parent` is created in a function that is only called after referencing it, but the function also destroys any children added to the parent... the list is too long. I would (honestly!) suggest you start from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use a javascript array to fill up a drop down select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255219/use-a-javascript-array-to-fill-up-a-drop-down-select-box)

Comment: I am assuming that your script is in the head of your html file, so whenever the code of the definition of `parent` and the subsequent for loop is processed, the `<select>` does not yet exist. I would suggest to wrap that part of the code in a function that is called as soon as the page is fully loaded. You can do that for example with `document.addEventListener`.

Comment: I'm new to javascript so I'm not totally clued up but if anybody could help me adjust the code accordingly it would be much appreciated so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Also should be noted my HTML is empty, and doesn't have any ID due to me wanting to do it through javascript

Comment: @Adam added leaflet tag. You'll get the answer more suited to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this method...

```
var police_api_dates = ["&date=2017-03",];

var info = L.control();


info.onAdd = function (mymap) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};


var S='';


for(var i=0; i<police_api_dates.length; i++){

  S=S+'<option value="'+i+'">'+police_api_dates[i]+'</option>';

}



info.update = function (properties) {

 info.innerHTML='<select id="parent">'+S+'</select>'+'<h4>Highlighted Postcode</h4>' + (properties ? '<b> Postcode: ' + properties.Name : 'Hover over a state');
};


parent.innerHTML=S; // Insert the options

parent.selectedIndex=3; // Set your default value


info.addTo(mymap);
```

NB: I would avoid using variable/ID names like "child" and "parent" because you're setting yourself up for javascript reserved word conflicts.

Updated code to get your sequence in order... let's see how that goes.

Comment: Having trouble implementing this into my code, i've replaced my code but fields still show empty.

Comment: Can you please use "P" instead of "parent" and maybe "C" instead of "child"  for variables/ID?

Comment: I have done, however I'm a bit lost it's still not working.

Comment: Try this... it's difficult to help you from a distance. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uteey91y/4/ This is updated using your code, as you can see no info dive box appears in the top.

Comment: Changed it again... try and follow the logic so you can fix it up your end because I don't have the whole picture from here.

Comment: I want a selection box above the hover over state box however the whole info div has disappeared now. compared to how it shouldlook here https://jsfiddle.net/e1syoc68/

Comment: What's wrong with the names `parent` and `child`? They're not reserved, and certainly more readable than `P` and `C`. `S` isn't too friendly, either.

Comment: Never concatenate arbitrary data into the context of HTML without properly escaping it.  Better to set things by properties.