# Create a dynamic select object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to populate the options of a select element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601028/how-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-element-in-javascript)

I would like to create a dynamic select tag and options tag in javascript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Although you've been a member for 7 months, I suggest you review the [faq#questions]. More importantly, [*what have you tried*](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 11):

try 
javascript

```
   var select = document.createElement( 'select' );
   var option;
   var inputdata = 123||456||789;

    inputdata.split( '||' ).forEach(function( item ) {

        option = document.createElement( 'option' );

        option.value = option.textContent =        item;

        select.appendChild( option );
    });
```

jquery

```
var inputdata = 123||456||789;
 var split = input.split('||');
 var select = $('<select name="options" id="options"></select>');
 $.each(split, function(index, value) {
   var option = $('<option></option>');
   option.attr('value', value);
   option.text(value);
   select.append(option);
 });
 $('#container).empty().append(select);
```

Comment: OP didn't say anything about jQuery.

Comment: @Mahn - updated with javascript also...

Comment: That was fast, upvoted :) (although there's a typo in the last  $('#container) =>  $('#container') )

Comment: Hmm not sure how a variable named 'select' is welcomed in IEs ...