# fill a <select> with a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I created a function which contains a string that I want to add to a  in HTML. But when I test it, it won't show me the options declared in my table.

```
function test(){
  // table already defined

  var choices = "<option selected>Select...</option>";

  for (var i=0; i<tableOptions.length; i++) {
    choices += "<option>" + tableOptions[i][0] +"</option>"; 
  }

  document.getElementById("theOptions").innerHTML = choices;
}
```

and in my HTML I have

```
<select id="theOptions"></select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, my test() is automatically loaded after my page is displayed.

```
<body onload="test()">
```

Comment: Is it just a typo or `tableOptions[i][0] +"</option>;";` really has a semi-colon after `</option>` on your code?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry.

Comment: pure javascript and not jquery?

Comment: Yes, I just started this week. Don't know anything about jquery yet. I thought I could just add a String with that function, but apparently I'm missing something.

Comment: What about the first option you've put in manually? `var choices = "<option selected>Select...</option>";` - does this show up on the select control? Also it would be good if you could provide a JSFiddle

Comment: innerHTML will allow you to append a text, not html element. You can refer to the below answer or [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) for a basic explaination.

Comment: Thanks joy-cs! this was very useful for me as I'm a beginner. So, I can not put a String into any tag but <p> ?

Comment: You can use innerHTML to write actual HTML over the contents any existing DOM element if you want to. It is a valid way to inject some new elements, technically, but it is generally not the best way to go about doing that. If you're creating new DOM elements, you should, in general, create the actual elements yourself and attach them (as I went through below) in the proper place. Using innerHTML can be useful when you have a payload already in HTML, like something off of an API or maybe some content from an asynchronous request or something like that.  Side note: please use MDN over W3Schools.

Comment: Thanks again @jimcavoli! my last question would be: Why is it better MDN over W3Schools?

Comment: Well, according to one's ability, I suppose, but it's neither authoritative, accurate, nor easily improved and while it has gotten better in recent years, it's been unreliable in the past, so I caution beginners over relying too heavily. There are better community and authoritative documentation that are emerging and in existence. http://www.w3fools.com does a decent job of summarizing the "why" if you'd like to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to populate the options of a select element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601028/how-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-element-in-javascript) for detail on creating and appending options to an existing `<select>` element.

Using that method, this seems closest to what you're getting at:

```
var select = document.getElementById("theOptions");
opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.innerHTML = "Select...";
select.appendChild(opt);

for(var i = 0; i < tableOptions.length; i++)
{
   var opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.innerHTML = tableOptions[i][0];
   select.appendChild(opt);
}
```