# select an option in already populated select tag using JS

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a `select` tag as following:

```
<select name='selectBox' id='selectBox'>
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3'>three</option>
    <option value='4'>four</option>
    <option value='5'>five</option>
</select>
```

and I have a value in a variable, for example: `selectVal = 'three'` and I want to select the option based on `text` not on `value`.

I looked on

```
$('#selectBox').prop('selectedIndex', 3);
$('#selectBox').selectmenu('refresh');
```

But I want to select on `text` of option. I'm beginner in this stuff, any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an option by its text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744289/how-to-select-an-option-by-its-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate the options of a select element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601028/how-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
var text = "five"
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectBox option').each(function(index){
    if($(this).text() === text){
        $('#selectBox').prop('selectedIndex', index);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the options index:

```
 var options = $("#selectBox > option");
 $('#selectBox').prop('selectedIndex', options.index(":contains(three)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way by using `each()`:

```js
let selectVal = 'three';
$('#selectBox option').each(function(){ 
  if($(this).text() == selectVal)
    $('#selectBox').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='selectBox' id='selectBox'>
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3'>three</option>
    <option value='4'>four</option>
    <option value='5'>five</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pure vanilla js

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.value = valueToSelect;
```