# How to populate select option:select dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am encountering an issue with double values appearing in the dropdown, contrary to what I want.
I have a shopping cart with a drop down from which a user can select a `cakesize` which has a price as its value.
My setup is a that the cart is stored in a session in the browser so that the value he selected is stored.
My issue is that when I load the page, the selected `cakesize` appears twice, On the **option selected** and on the list.

```
<select name="cakesize" class="custom-select cakesize">
    <option selected value="<%=cake.currentPrice%>"><%=cake.currentCakeSize %></option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['1000'] %>">1kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['1500'] %>">1.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['2000'] %>">2kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['2500'] %>">2.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['3000'] %>">3kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['3500'] %>">3.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['4000'] %>">4kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['4500'] %>">4.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['5000'] %>">5kg</option>
 </select>
```

Is it okay for it to remain this way?

Comment: Your code does not clear your question, share more details that how your site is  storing and retrieving sessions.

Comment: You can check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601028/how-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-element-in-javascript

Comment: One solution might be add an `if` block around each `<option>`, hide it if the value matches the selected size. Something like this: `if cake.item.price['1000']  !== cake.currentPrice`

Comment: @SonNguyen Thank you. This seems like the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is as follows

```html
<select name="cakesize" class="custom-select cakesize">

    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['1000'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['1000'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >1kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['1500'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['1500'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >1.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['2000'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['2000'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >2kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['2500'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['2500'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >2.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['3000'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['3000'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >3kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['3500'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['3500'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >3.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['4000'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['4000'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >4kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['4500'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['4500'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >4.5kg</option>
    <option value="<%=cake.item.price['5000'] %>" <%=cake.currentPrice == cake.item.price['5000'] ? 'selected' : '' %> >5kg</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Amazing! This did it! Thank you