# Can`t fill select with options

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to fill select with array values.

Here is js code (which I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601028/how-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-element-in-javascript)). It doesn't work even without loop. So if I could make it work, then filling with array won`t be a problem.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('CountrySelect');     
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.innerHTML = "CountyNumerOne";
opt.value = 0;
sel.appendChild(opt);
```

```html
<select id="CountrySelect">
</select>
```

But on the output I get empty list

Comment: As you can see from having changed your exact code to be a [mcve] the code works just fine, so there is some difference between what you have here and what's going on in your real project. My guess is you're running the javascript before the `select` element is on the page.

Comment: @Jamiec oh, Im such a noob. Ive moved script to the end and now its working. Thank you!

Comment: Ha, don't be hard on yourself. We've all made a similar mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure the script is triggered after the select element is parsed by the browser. You can do this either by putting the script tag after your select element, or listening for the document loaded event in your script:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var sel = document.getElementById('CountrySelect');
    
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = "CountyNumerOne";
        opt.value = 0;
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = document.getElementById("CountrySelect"); 
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //array
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yYW89/